# Svg Balloon thread animation

Tags: html, css, svg, smil

I am trying to achieve `animation for a balloon`. I want the thread to move a bit as if the `balloon` is floating in the air. I am able to get the movement but for some reason the position of the thread has gone wrong. I understand the positioning values of thread is wrong but how do i match it with the balloon?

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="595.28" height="841.89" viewPort="0 0 595.28 841.89">
  <g>
    <path id="thread" fill="none" stroke="#010101" d="M 302 540 l 1 -150">
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" values="M60 302 c0 10 -10 90 0 131;
                     M60 302 c0 10 3 90 0 136;
                     M60 302 c0 10 10 90 0 138;
                     M60 302 c0 10 -3 90 0 136;
                     M60 302 c0 10 -10 90 0 131" keyTimes="0; 0.25; 0.5; 0.75; 1" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#EF393C" stroke-width="1.028" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M318.682 354.28c-25.82-22.654-68.935 16.096-49.36 46.686 15.468 24.175 49.806 30.21 66.513 5.493 8.354-12.358 9.695-25.44 1.834-39.134-6.35-11.054-20.36-19.99-30.232-19.99"></path>
    <path fill="#EF393C" d="M338.955 371.226c-.933-2.055-1.78-4.726-3.24-6.524-.73-.903-1.504-1.738-2.353-2.547-.828-.783-1.63-1.45-2.41-2.053-3.12-2.377-4.55-5.104-7.417-6.565-.697-.35-.936-.977-1.63-1.302-1.694-2.052-4.723-1.792-7.653-3.91-2.03-.31-3.71-1.208-6.188-1.303-1.238-.044-2.98-.385-4.36-.29-.675.046-1.396.12-2.223.233-.79.116-1.867-.505-2.638-.317-1.222.11-1.923.284-3.247.465-1.267.175-2.32.325-3.94.694-1.524.362-2.95.867-4.406 1.392-2.9 1.084-6.554 2.604-8.812 4.636-1.528 1.367-2.778 1.75-3.876 3.456-.605.43-1.726 1.653-2.28 2.117-1.227 1.016-1.982 2.665-2.78 3.54-1.71 1.882-2.156 3.628-3.393 6.304-.48 1.042-1.71 3.7-2.046 4.91-.918 2.237-1.293 6.39-1.637 8.8-.43 2.94.146 5.817.52 8.548.374 2.736 1.067 5.28 1.936 7.616 1.75 4.68 3.137 7.178 5.728 10.64 2.608 3.458 5.764 6.442 8.8 9.208 1.323 1.27 2.26 2.32 3.48 2.66 1.355 2.065 3.347 1.8 5.576 3.446.28.206.564.41.857.61.433.29.875.576 1.324.853.897.555 1.82 1.077 2.767 1.557 1.892.962 3.866 1.757 5.875 2.264.417.103.837.188 1.258.268-1.608 1.887-1.022 2.784-.944 2.887.19.247.51.385.886.384.03 0 .06.006.09-.002.297-.068.606-.03 1.06-.642.246.35 1.366.53 2.106.633.47.063.914-.22 1.104-.707.11-.283.305-1.128-.653-2.262.395-.017.788-.036 1.183-.092 2.018-.298 3.92-1.01 5.77-1.93 1.846-.922 3.622-2.02 5.37-3.138l1.308-.846.62-.405.425-.248c.56-.33.896-.708 1.457-1.004l1.092-.836c2.068-1.81 3.067-2.996 3.746-3.257 2.39-2.125 2.548-2.06 4.785-4.49 1.12-1.222 1.73-2.037 2.865-3.478.568-.727 1.566-2.566 2.17-3.447.3-.44.603-.908.943-1.462.273-.46.52-.893.755-1.325 1.876-3.475 2.75-6.212 3.664-9.858.896-3.645 1.266-7.83 1.16-11.826-.118-3.973-.685-7.924-2.555-12.054zm-47.22 1.378c.04-.043.075-.096.114-.14-.003.045-.036.093-.116.14zm10.388 2.03c.03.008.063.02.094.027l.01.003.11.032c-.08.038-.156.082-.24.12 0-.068.016-.122.026-.18zm2.568 3.93H304.7h-.01zm.345-.048c.035-.004.074-.012.107-.015l.08-.004h.03c-.072.002-.145.012-.217.02z"></path>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A translate transform can move the path.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="595.28" height="841.89" viewPort="0 0 595.28 841.89">
  <g>
    <path id="thread" transform="translate(242, 130)" fill="none" stroke="#010101" d="M 302 540 l 1 -150">
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" values="M60 302 c0 10 -10 90 0 131;
                     M60 302 c0 10 3 90 0 136;
                     M60 302 c0 10 10 90 0 138;
                     M60 302 c0 10 -3 90 0 136;
                     M60 302 c0 10 -10 90 0 131" keyTimes="0; 0.25; 0.5; 0.75; 1" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#EF393C" stroke-width="1.028" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M318.682 354.28c-25.82-22.654-68.935 16.096-49.36 46.686 15.468 24.175 49.806 30.21 66.513 5.493 8.354-12.358 9.695-25.44 1.834-39.134-6.35-11.054-20.36-19.99-30.232-19.99"></path>
    <path fill="#EF393C" d="M338.955 371.226c-.933-2.055-1.78-4.726-3.24-6.524-.73-.903-1.504-1.738-2.353-2.547-.828-.783-1.63-1.45-2.41-2.053-3.12-2.377-4.55-5.104-7.417-6.565-.697-.35-.936-.977-1.63-1.302-1.694-2.052-4.723-1.792-7.653-3.91-2.03-.31-3.71-1.208-6.188-1.303-1.238-.044-2.98-.385-4.36-.29-.675.046-1.396.12-2.223.233-.79.116-1.867-.505-2.638-.317-1.222.11-1.923.284-3.247.465-1.267.175-2.32.325-3.94.694-1.524.362-2.95.867-4.406 1.392-2.9 1.084-6.554 2.604-8.812 4.636-1.528 1.367-2.778 1.75-3.876 3.456-.605.43-1.726 1.653-2.28 2.117-1.227 1.016-1.982 2.665-2.78 3.54-1.71 1.882-2.156 3.628-3.393 6.304-.48 1.042-1.71 3.7-2.046 4.91-.918 2.237-1.293 6.39-1.637 8.8-.43 2.94.146 5.817.52 8.548.374 2.736 1.067 5.28 1.936 7.616 1.75 4.68 3.137 7.178 5.728 10.64 2.608 3.458 5.764 6.442 8.8 9.208 1.323 1.27 2.26 2.32 3.48 2.66 1.355 2.065 3.347 1.8 5.576 3.446.28.206.564.41.857.61.433.29.875.576 1.324.853.897.555 1.82 1.077 2.767 1.557 1.892.962 3.866 1.757 5.875 2.264.417.103.837.188 1.258.268-1.608 1.887-1.022 2.784-.944 2.887.19.247.51.385.886.384.03 0 .06.006.09-.002.297-.068.606-.03 1.06-.642.246.35 1.366.53 2.106.633.47.063.914-.22 1.104-.707.11-.283.305-1.128-.653-2.262.395-.017.788-.036 1.183-.092 2.018-.298 3.92-1.01 5.77-1.93 1.846-.922 3.622-2.02 5.37-3.138l1.308-.846.62-.405.425-.248c.56-.33.896-.708 1.457-1.004l1.092-.836c2.068-1.81 3.067-2.996 3.746-3.257 2.39-2.125 2.548-2.06 4.785-4.49 1.12-1.222 1.73-2.037 2.865-3.478.568-.727 1.566-2.566 2.17-3.447.3-.44.603-.908.943-1.462.273-.46.52-.893.755-1.325 1.876-3.475 2.75-6.212 3.664-9.858.896-3.645 1.266-7.83 1.16-11.826-.118-3.973-.685-7.924-2.555-12.054zm-47.22 1.378c.04-.043.075-.096.114-.14-.003.045-.036.093-.116.14zm10.388 2.03c.03.008.063.02.094.027l.01.003.11.032c-.08.038-.156.082-.24.12 0-.068.016-.122.026-.18zm2.568 3.93H304.7h-.01zm.345-.048c.035-.004.074-.012.107-.015l.08-.004h.03c-.072.002-.145.012-.217.02z"></path>
  </g>

</svg>
```